# SSRS report with muliple datasets

Tags: reporting-services

I have added a separate dataset to an SSRS report...it contains some similar tables as another dataset.  When I go to write expressions the fields in my new dataset have a "SUM" in front of the field numeric fields and "First" in front of the char fields???  Now I can't pick the numeric field for my report because it will "SUM" up all the data

Comment: It sounds like you have some **Grouping** on the table and SSRS is automatically converting them to a SUM. You should remove the grouping, otherwise SSRS will just display the **first** value in the dataset rather than **ALL** of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the SUM() portion once you add the field. Perhaps it is there because of the scope of the bound item. There is no harm in removing the aggregate if the field is in a position in which a detail can print SUM(X)=X.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on the heels of Ross' answer...

You can remove those [SUM(FIELD)] tags from your table by clicking it and hitting delete. To add the single data value you want to display, type the field name in brackets like [FIELD] right into that text box.

Alternately, edit the expression the be:

> *=Fields!YOURFIELDNAME.Value*