# Building SSRS Report from multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2012

Hi I am trying to construct SSRS report using multiple `datasets`. The report is about hotel details like hotel id, name, city, link to website and hotel specific details. Below is the screenshot of datasets:

[image]

`BackupReport` contains the hotel id, name, city, etc and `BackupSubReport` contains other hotel specific metadata.

Below is my report Design layout:

[image]

Now when I preview the report, I get hotel id, name and city for all hotels first, then hotel links for all hotels and then finally the hotel metadata like below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The actual report should look like this:

[image]

Any idea on how to fix that. I am new to SSRS so not much familiar with all the design specifics. I checked this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960932/ssrs-report-with-muliple-datasets) but that is about a specific function. I read about `lookup` and `multilookup` functions but not sure how can I apply them here to fix my issue?

Any comments will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your desired result is in SSRS normally a subreport, where you have in the main report all hotel Id´s and if you click one id you go to the subreport with the detaildata (like in your picture).

In SSRS you normally have all data for one hotel id in one row. If you have two datasets, you combine the data with `Lookup()`. Put a tablix in your report and add in the first two textboxes the fields `Hotel ID` and `Vendor Name` from the dataset `BackupReport`:

```
'Data from DataSet1
| APA-HotelParsing_HotelID | VendorName |

'Data from DataSet1 combined with DataSet2
| APA-HotelParsing_HotelID | VendorName | GoogleValue |
```

To get `Google Value` write the following expression in the third textbox:

```
=Lookup(Fields!APA-HotelParsing_HotelID.Value, Fields!APA-HotelParsing_HotelID.Value, Fields!GoogleValue.Value, "BackupSubReport")
```

Apply the lookup step again and get all your data in one row.

If you dont want to work with subreport and just display the data like in your picture you can do a workaround and put all data in one textbox. Thus it will look like your pictire. You have to write a expression like this in the tablix detail textbox:

```
="Hotel ID: " & Fields!APA-HotelParsing_HotelID.Value & Space(10) & 
 "AA Hotel Name: " & Fields!VendorName.Value & Space(10) & 
 "City Code: " & Fields!CityCode.Value & VbNewLine & 
 Lookup(Fields!APA-HotelParsing_HotelID.Value, 
        Fields!APA-HotelParsing_HotelID.Value, 
        Fields!GoogleValue.Value, "BackupSubReport"
        )
```

And so on... This way you get all information in one textbox and because it is in the detail section it will get automatically repeated for each row.